# Hôpital / hospitalier : why the s in the latter?

Tags: vocabulaire, orthographe, diacritiques

A hospital is *l’hôpital* and I know that a *centre hospitalier* is a place where there is more than just a hospital. However, why is there an *s* in *hospitalier*?  I have asked many French friends and they have all struggled to find the answer. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: It's “h**ô**pital”. A very important detail for this particular question.

Comment: Hi, yes thanks I know but unfortunately i can't seem to be able to find out how to insert these characters such as e, a with accents.  Bit of a technophobe in that regard.  Is that why there is a difference between the spelling of hopital and hospitalier because the o is accented?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the time you have taken to give me such a comprehensive answer. I can now tell my French friends who will be as interested as me.
This is the first time I have used this site but I am sure that it will not be the last.

Answer (score 8):

As you can see from the "disappearance of s" section in [Circumflex in French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex_in_French), the ^ indicates (in this case) that the word hôpital used to have a "silent" S. It indeed comes from the word "hospitalia" in Latin, which gave "ospital" in old French. The "s" became silent in the 11th century and was replaced with ^. Some words of the same family, such as "hospitalisation", came after the 11th century and took the original Latin word as a template.

Note that there are other examples with adjectives

> fête -> festif
>
> forêt -> forestier
>
> bête -> bestial

but there is no general rule as it depends on the date of "creation" of the word

> côte -> côtier
>
> hôtel -> hôtelier

Comment: Another example where etymology sheds some light: "châtaigne" and "castagne" (a slang word for a brawl, where you are likely to give and take a couple of "châtaignes", ie punches) both come from the Latin "castanea", but "castagne" came to French via occitan dialects and therefore kept its "s".

Answer (score 5):

There is an S in *hospitalier* because the word comes from the latin *hospitalia*. So the question is rather why *hôpital* lost its S, while other words in the same family such as *hospitalier* didn't.

There is a very common phenomenon in French where certain words in a family are close to their Latin original, while a few have changed more. This is known as *formation savante* vs. *formation populaire* (or *dérivation savante* vs. *dérivation populaire*), i.e. scholarly vs. popular derivation. Scholarly derivations have retained a form that is close to the Latin original, while popular derivations have evolved over a long period of time. Often, the main noun or verb in a family has undergone continuous popular derivation since Late Latin, whereas other “highbrow” words were introduced later by scholars. Usually the popular derivation is a simplification, with some sounds removed and possibly other sounds changed.

In the case of *hôpital*, the “basic” noun lost its S sound during the Middle Ages. French spelling was standardized in the 16th and 17th centuries based on a compromise between pronunciation and etymology. The [circumflex accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex_in_French#Indication_of_a_lost_phoneme) was added in this and many other words to indicate that a letter (usually S) had been removed during the word's history. The “fancy” adjective *hospitalier* and the “fancy” noun *hospitalité* kept a more complicated form (with one more sound).

By the way, in modern French, the spelling and pronunciation *[hôpitalier](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/h%C3%B4pitalier)* are gaining ground for the meaning “related to hospitals”. The spelling and pronunciation *hospitalier* are the only possible ones for the meaning “hospitable”.

Scholarly/popular pairs distinguished by S/circumflex are fairly common. Here are a few other examples, including some with further evolution of the popular form:

- *pastoral* vs. *pâtre*, *pâturage* (pastoral vs. pastor/shepherd, pasture/meadow). Note how there is a similar phenomenon in English where the “fancy” adjective has a Latin origin but there are more “day-to-day” nouns with a German origin)
- *mâcher*, *mâchonner* vs. *mastication*, *mastiquer* (chew, “chew negligently” vs. “action of chewing”, “chew carefully”)
- *fête*, *fêter* vs. *festif*, *festival* (party/festival/celebration, celebrate vs. festive, (a fancier kind of) festival)
- *côté* vs. *accoster* (side vs. “to get alongside”)
- *goût*, *goûter* vs. *gustatif* (taste (noun), taste (verb) vs. gustative). Here the popular derivation acquired an extra letter to indicate the shifted pronunciation (`ou` or `oû` is pronounced [u], a mere `u` or `û` would be pronounced [y]).
- *août*, *auguste* (August (the month), august)

Scholarly/popular pairs don't have to involve circumflex accents, that's just one of many possibilities. Here are a few other examples.

- *chien* vs. *canin* (dog vs. “related to dogs”)
- *cheval*, *chevalier* vs. *cavalier*, *cavaler* (horse, knight vs. “horse rider”, “ride fast”)
- *poisson*, *poissonnier* vs. *pêche*, *pêcher* vs. *pisciculture*, *piscine* (fish (noun), fishmonger vs. fishing, to fish vs. “fish farming”, “swimming pool”)
- *domaine* vs. *dominer* (domain vs. dominate)
- *main* vs. *manuel* (hand vs. “by hand”)
- *été* vs. *estival* (summer vs. “related to summer”), *école* vs. *scolaire* (school vs. “related to schooling”), ... The transformation of the initial es- into é is a process that had already started in Latin, where words beginning with S and certain other consonants had acquired a leading E. This leading E was pronounced [e] in French, and became spelled `é`, rather than `ê` which would have been pronounced [ɛ].
- *voir*, *vue* vs. *vision*, *visuel* (see, sight vs. vision, visual). Here the words had already started to diverge in classical Latin: vid- for some tenses including the “basic” present indicative form vs. vis- in more complex tenses.

By the way, you can spot a similar duality in English with German basic words and Latin fancy words. The historical mechanism for that is rather different (and off-topic here), but both languages ended up with a large number of popular/scholarly pairs.

Note that while the scholarly/popular duality is widespread enough to be a recognizable feature of the language, it is by no means universal. There are many word families that have only a single root. Some examples of families where an S has been replaced by a circumflex accent in all modern French words are *île* (island, from Lat. *insula*), *pâte* (pasta, from It. *pasta*), *âne* (donkey, from Lat. *asinus*), *hâte* (haste, from an ancestor language of German) …